# accessing a class from another class

Tags: php, oop, class

I have an idea which requires loading in another class. Let's say I have index.php that includes once (database.php). In a class, **is it acceptable** to create a new object that is not extended by the class? In otherwords, brining in the content globally instead? Here's what I mean...

```
index.php:
----------------------
include_once ('./core/dataAccess.php');

....

class home {
    private function getUsers() {
        $dataAccess = new DataAccess();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course this is acceptable!

Comment: No, it is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's acceptable and widely used practice, however it is in most cases not the *best* solution. The advanced way is using *dependency injection*, which means that any other objects needed by your class will be " injected" from the outside, making them interchangeable. This could happen in the constructor, in a setter method or directly as parameter where they are needed.

The only methods that use the `new` keyword are then factory methods that do nothing else than creating objects.